# How to start sshd on Puppy Linux?

Tags: sshd, puppy-linux

I have installed sshd on puppy linux. Can someone tell me how to start sshd on it?

Answer (score 1):

I found useful instructions to setup sshd (ssh server) on Bionic Puppy Linux here: [PuppyLinuxNewsletter - December 2018](http://smokey01.com/newsletters/2018/December/0024-PuppyLinuxNewsletter-December2018.html)

1. SSH should be installed in all puppies by default. Despite the name, this is only the client part of SSH, which allows one to log in to a host computer running another OS such as Raspberry Pi, Ubuntu, Antix, etc. Confirm this installation by looking for the ssh_config file in /etc/ssh. It is not necessary to edit this file, although in some cases a change in permissions of this file may be required to run as server.

   If another Linux Distro (eg Ubuntu) is running an SSH server on the same LAN, you can test the operation of the Puppy as a client as per step 10. This is not essential because we can test the operation of the SSH-client on the local or host device as per step 8 as part of the setup.
2. To run SSH as a server, one needs to install SSHD - the SSH Daemon Server, which listens at port 22 (or otherwise configured) for clients requesting access to the Host Secure Shell. The host software Openssh-server can be installed from the PPM. As of LX Bionic pup, the version is 7.6p1, and on earlier Tahrpuppies it is 6.6.1p1.
3. After installation of Openssh-server from the PPM, open the main SSH folder found at `/etc/ssh`. This folder must have two config files: `ssh_config` and `sshd_config`, plus a file called moduli.

   In the likely event that the default `sshd_config` file does *not* exist, download the script from:
   https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/sshd_config

   This script must be pasted into a newly created text file, or an existing shell script which is gutted, populated with the sshd script and then re-named. Permissions may need to be changed to make the file editable or accessible.

   Failing that, copy the file from another operating Linux distribution where SSHD is installed. However, it is better to start with a default script.
4. The `sshd_config` file must now be edited to operate under Puppy Linux.

   From experience, some of the lines below in the script seem to be more critical than others, as indicated in the RHS (#) comments. Remove any “#” comment tags on the LHS of the lines listed below and edit as shown. Optional lines should be able to be left as comments as these are the default configurations.

   ```
   Port 22 # Optional, as this is the default
   AddressFamily any # Optional ?
   LoginGraceTime 2m # Optional 
   PermitRootLogin yes # Critical for puppy linux
   PubkeyAuthentication no # Critical for initial use
   PasswordAuthentication yes # Critical for initial use 
   PermitEmptyPasswords yes # Optional, otherwise use no
   ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes # Critical for initial use
   UsePAM no # Critical
   AllowTcpForwarding yes # Optional ?
   X11Forwarding yes # If one wishes to run GUI applications in the host computer 
   X11DisplayOffset 10 # Recommended
   X11UseLocalhost yes # Optional ?
   PrintMotd no # Optional ?
   TCPKeepAlive yes # Optional ?
   Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server # Optional ?
   ```
5. One is now ready to start the SSHD server in the terminal: `/etc/init.d/ssh start`.
   There should be error messages displayed, as not all features have been setup. Ignore these for now.
6. In any case, one can now check that SSH is running.
   In the terminal run `netstat -tupan` which will give a list of ALL ports on which the host device is listening.
   The line(s) we are seeking references port 22, which looks like the following:

   ```
   Active Internet connections (servers and established)
   Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State PID/Program name
   tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 6866/sshd
   ```

   For a shorter output, which only lists port 22, use: `netstat -anplt | grep :22` (care with spaces)
   which, if SSHD is operating should give:

   ```
   tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 6866/sshd
   ```

   No listing of port 22 will mean that SSH is not running and the setup will need checking.
7. The next step is to check that the files `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` are correctly set.
   Apparently, as Puppy Linux runs with “root” as user, the OS is setup to automatically disallow access to most ports as a safety measure.

   Remove or comment with a `# ALL: ALL` in `hosts.deny` and change the data in `hosts.allow` to:

   ```
   ALL: LOCAL
   SSH: ALL
   ```

   This tweak is also critical in other applications which require remote access, such as streaming music using MPD.
8. Ensure your firewall is turned off for the testing of the local SSH. SSHD should be able to connect into the local host before any attempt is made to use a separate client device.

   Test the setup in the terminal using : `ssh -vvv root@localhost`
   *or* `ssh -vvv root@127.0.0.1` ( where `127.0.0.1` is the IP address of the localhost determined by the use of `ifconfig`).

   Setting the switch to `-vvv` will give an extended verbose output in order to see where the operation stopped. For less information, use `-v` instead.

   It is likely that SSHD will run until the following error is reported:

   ```
   debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
   Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer 
   OR ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
   OR ssh_exchange_identification: read: Closed by unknown
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You typically can start services on Puppy using `/etc/init.d` scripts.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/sshd start
```

If you find that it's already running, like so:

```
$ netstat -anplt | grep :22 
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22     0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22          :::*           LISTEN      -
```

Then you know that the daemon is running and listening on port 22. If that's the case then your issue is likely related to this issue dicussed in this thread, titled: [Can't ssh to puppy machine- connection refused.](http://www.murga-linux.com/puppy/viewtopic.php?p=675148&sid=86081cbcec000c0daa92770e41bd8228)  .

Here there's a firewall enabled with Puppy, that either needs to have a rule added, that allows SSH access in, or needs to be disabled. For this you'll need to use `iptables` to manipulate the firewall. For example:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```